# "Only one offer per customer" on a coupon

Tags: meaning-in-context

If a coupon lists four offers (including a discount, free delivery, buy-one-get-one-free, etc.) and has "Only one offer per customer" printed on it, can we conclude this is a single-use coupon as opposed to a multi-use coupon?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you asking if "only one offer per customer" is idiomatic coupon-speak?

Comment: I'd like to know how to interpret that string of words. I'd think it means offers cannot be combined, but an Australian told me it entails the coupon can only be used once.

Comment: It depends on whether you understand those four choices to be the "offers" referred to in the disclaimer.  If there's room for misunderstanding, you might want to make the disclaimer less terse.

Comment: If ""One coupon per customer" is used instead, does it necessarily mean that the coupon can only be used once?

Comment: No it does not *necessarily* mean that it can be used only once.   It could be a coupon for 50% discount  on matinee movies which is valid through the month of August.  It might be valid for 31 showings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Only one offer per customer" is an unclear statement. If the coupon has four offers on it, then clearly any customer who gets a coupon has four offers, not one. I'd GUESS that what it means is that any one customer can only take advantage of one of the four offers. You can pick one of the four.

But it's possible that they mean that you can only use the coupon once. Especially if the coupon does not identify the four discounts as "offers", the store might think of these as "four discounts" and the coupon is an "offer". In that case it might mean that you can only use one coupon, that is, you can't get two copies of the coupon and use one today and the other tomorrow.

If I was creating the coupon, I'd use more words to explain what I meant.